# ODP / NSF sync. not working

Tags: git, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

I try to use GIT with a NSF project
My issue is not with GIT, but I have problems with the sync between Domino and the ODP version of the project.
By checking out an older version of the project, a deleted form reapers in the ODP as expected
However, I cannot get this form to show up in DDE, mot even in the eclipse navigation view.
I have tried to manually update with "Sync with ODP" without any luck

If I cannot trust the ODP / NSF synchronization, this is kind of a show stopper for me. Has anyone else experienced the same? I'm on 8.5.3 fp4

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this as well.  The file is there but in DDE you can't see it.  What ends up working for me is to select the folder the file should be in and then do a refresh (F9 I think or you can right-click and choose refresh).  Do this for the ODP and then if you manually sync with the db or do a build on the db (which should automatically do a sync with the ODP) then you should see the file show up.